# How do i sum all numbers using loop?

Tags: c++, loops

For Example, I have number 1 + 6 + 7 + 12 + 13 + 18+.....+ n (n is the input from users which represent the number of elements)  the index of this number starts from 1 by this it means​ that if the index is an odd number (1,3,5...) I want to increment the element at that index by 5 and if the index is an even number I want to increment the element at that index by 1 until I reach the of n number of elements. What I want is to sum all those numbers.
Sorry, It may hard to understand because of my poor English So let me write some of my C code here:

```cpp
using namespace std;

  int i, n, result = 0;

  cout << "Input number to sum: ";
  cin >> n;

  // Finding result
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      result +=i;
    } else {
      result += i * 5;
    }
  }

  // Make last number have equal sign "1+6+7+12 = 36"
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    if (i == n) {
      cout << i..?? << "=";
    } else {
      cout << i..?? << "+";
    }
  }

  // Print result out
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that 1+6+7+12 = 36 ? math says that it's 26. And what is N? If it represents the number of elements then for loop should be (i = 0; i < n; i++) or (i = 1; i <= n; i++), but in your example N is upper bound of summing numbers

Comment: Sorry I've confused. I mean N is n . I edited

Answer (score 0):

Combine the computation with the output (I usually preach the opposite, but in this case it actually simplifies matters).

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    int value = i % 2 == 0 ? i + 1 : i + 5;
    cout << (i > 0 ? " + " : "") << value;
    result += value;
}
cout << " = " << result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) that combining calculations and output in this case, simplify the code.

I don't agree with the algorithm, though, given OP's description.

In the following the calculations are repeated to output the result

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n; 
    std::cout << "Input number to sum: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    auto update = [] (int i) { return i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 5; };

    int result = 0;
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        value += update(i);
        result += value;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0, value = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        value += update(i);
        std::cout << (i > 0 ? " + " : "") << value;
    }
    std::cout << " = " << result;
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ns3fKq).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo)'s answer. However the algorithm some changes.

1. The index starts from 1 , so value check for i in for loop should be

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
2. while updating the values, increment should be done on value and not on i.

Here is my solution:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n, result, value = 0;
    cout << "Input number to sum: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        value = i % 2 == 0 ? value + 1 : value + 5;
        cout << (i > 0 ? " + " : "") << value;
        result += value;
    }
    cout << " = " << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8baZn9)